# Magento 2 not displaying payment methods on frontend

Tags: magento2, checkout

I am having this problem on my **magento 2** website.

Whenever a **logged in or guest user** adds a **product to cart** and then **proceeds to checkout** , all **payment methods** are displayed correctly on the checkout page.

However, in another scenario if  a logged in or guest user adds a product to cart and then proceeds to checkout and before proceeding to actually doing the payment if the user clicks "Edit" tab to edit his/her personal information and comes to back to the payment page then "No Payment methods" is being displayed on the frontend.

Errors displayed in cosole are as follows :

> 1.) Uncaught TypeError: items is not a function
>       at collection.min.js:8
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (underscore.min.js:7)
>       at UiClass._updateCollection (collection.min.js:8)
>       at UiClass.removeChild (collection.min.js:5)
>       at UiClass. (element.min.js:19)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at UiClass._clearRefs (element.min.js:19)
>       at UiClass.destroy (element.min.js:18)
>       at UiClass._super (wrapper.min.js:3)
>       at UiClass.destroy (collection.min.js:7)
>
> 2.) Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "blockLoader: function (){return isLoading }" Message: isLoading is not defined
>       at blockLoader (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.min.js:268), :3:64)
>       at update (block-loader.min.js:7)
>       at ko.dependentObservable.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved
>
> 3.) Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
>       at JSON.parse ()
>       at Object.process
>
> 4.) Facebook Pixel Error: Error: Duplicate Pixel ID: 1165366550167867

Can anyone help me out in solving out this problem ?

Comment: are you enabled payment method for guest checkout.

Comment: yes i have enabled for guests as well. By the way same problem arises for logged in user as well